# OOP vs Functional - Measuring performance between implementation of same thing

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming

Currently i'm developing this Firebird module to help me work with some database files, and i'm in doubt between OOP vs Functional. The code:

Functional:

```
import kinterbasedb


def create_cursor(dsn, user, password):
  return connect(dsn=dsn, user=user, password=password).cursor()

def execute(database_cursor, query, fetch):
  database_cursor.execute(query)
  if fetch == "*":
    return database_cursor.fetchall()
  return database_cursor.fetchone()
```

Then:

```
from firebird import create_cursor, execute

database_cursor = create_cursor(dsn="some/database", user="someuser", password="somepassword")
result = execute(database_cursor, fetch="*")
```

Vs:

```
class Firebird(object):

  cursor = None

  def __init__(self, dsn, user, password):
    self.dsn = dsn
    self.user = user
    self.password = password

  def create_cursor(self):
    connection = kinterbasedb.connect(dsn=self.dsn,
                                      user=self.user,
                                      password=self.password)
    self.cursor = connection.cursor()

  def execute(self, query, fetch):
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    if fetch == "*":
      return self.cursor.fetchall()
    return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Then

```
from firebird import Firebird


database = Firebird(dsn="some/database", user="someuser", password="somepassword")
database.create_cursor()
result_from_query = database.execute(query="SOME QUERY", fetch="*")
```

How could i choose between this two implementations? I'm more an functional person, i love working with this paradigm, but i'm worried about affecting performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Both look perfectly fine to me but that could be because I like functional programing more. I would simply change the `return` to `yield` when it just fetches one row.

Comment: The answers to this will be completely subjective.  Also, functional versus object-oriented is more of a design choice.  Ideally, it shouldn't affect your performance.  In reality, things aren't always ideal so you should try running benchmarks on the performance.

Comment: I don't think this is subjective. I would like know more about performance when using functional vs oop in python.

Comment: Could you show me the yield implementation pretty please? @Ev. Kounis

Comment: Based on the implementations you showed above, the functional code will probably execute faster (on average) because it avoids attribute lookups on an instance.  With that said, it won't execute much faster -- the database accessing will take WAY more time and I would be completely shocked if one or the other was noticeably faster...

Comment: Hm, the problem is that i'm working with this functions in a looping with 10k+ database files.

Comment: @CantFindMe just replace `return` with `yield`. `yield` "transforms" your function into a generator on which features `__next__`. Do spent some time reading on generators. They are like on demand item providers. Instead of returning the entire list for example they allow you to loop through it by feeding you one item at a time

Comment: @CantFindMe These are more than *"some"*

Comment: I'm curious, why the database access would take way more time in the functional implementation?

Comment: Thanks guys, you are really helping me!

Comment: @CantFindMe I think he's saying that no matter how you implement the python side, the majority of your time is going to be spent accessing the database

Comment: functional and objective are not mutual exclusive.